# Oauth Foursquare on Android device

Tags: java, android, oauth, foursquare

I am using this tutorial here to allow the user to sign in to Foursqaure on an android device http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/10/oauth-flow-in-android-app/ What are the parameters that I would use here, as foursquare only has authenticate and access token retrieval:

```
this.provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
                    REQUEST_URL,
                    ACCESS_URL,
                    AUTHORIZE_URL);
```

Is there any other tutorials that may be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this post : http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/web/oauth

It mentions the following OAuth endpoints

```
static final String FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN = "http://foursquare.com/oauth/request_token";
static final String FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN = "http://foursquare.com/oauth/access_token";
static final String FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE = "http://foursquare.com/oauth/authorize";
```

Keep in mind that the blog post and endpoints above are only valid for FourSquare V1 API.

V2 API uses OAuth 2.0. you might want to checkout the [Leelo project](https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0/wiki/Home) for an OAuth 2.0 implementation that seems to work on Android.

Comment: is this not using V1, should I not change to V2 for signing in on android?

Comment: You didn't mention V1 or V2  API in your question :) The signpost example mentioned on the blog is only Oauth 1.0 compliant. I've updated the answer

Comment: I am using Foursquare V2 not OAuth so would the above leelo link be suitable?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I know some have validated it on Android. So I think it's worth investigating....